# Oracle measuring execution time stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I would like to measure the execution time of a stored procedure in Oracle. I have learned about the technique of writing an entry in a temporary logging table at the start and the end but am unable to use this technique.

Can you refer me to an open source/free tool with which I'm able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Tyler Muth's `logger` library. It's the closest thing to an industry standard. [Check it out](https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on your environment you are using.

If you are using **SQLPlus**, you can enable a timer as follows :t

```
SQL> set timing on
```

Then, just execute your procedure, like :

```
SQL> exec my_procedure;
```

When the procedure will complete, a summary line will be displayed, like :

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:03.05
```

From within **PL/SQL**, you can use `dbms_utility.get_time` :

```
DECLARE 
    start_time pls_integer;
BEGIN
    start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    exec my_procedure;
    dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - start_time)/100 || ' seconds');
END;
/
```

Should output something like :

```
3 seconds

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

See [this excellent explanation from Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=excecution-time-of-a-procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Execution of the stored procedure's start /end time can be logged using 
`DBMS_UTILITY.get_cpu_time` or `DBMS_UTILITY.get_time`

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc IS
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('start time '||DBMS_UTILITY.get_time);
 <your statement>

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('end time '||DBMS_UTILITY.get_time);

END;
```

There are of course other ways of finding the execution time using [Profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm#CHDCIGIB)

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050233/599528) as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get details that can actually help you diagnose issues, I highly recommend dbms_profiler.

It is easy to use and provides statistics for every line in the pl/sql including number of executions, total time, min and max.